# Error using LIBSVM's svmtrain on Matlab: C <= 0

Tags: matlab, libsvm

Dataset: http://www.amlbook.com/data/zip/features.train

I am taking "Learning from Data" online at Caltech. Last week we had an assignment where we had to use Support Vector Machines to classify digits. I did the assignment, got everything right.

This week, I tried running my scripts again, and I"m getting an error when I try to use svmtrain from libsvm: Error: C <= 0.

The C here is the parameter C in soft-margin SVM.

```
class1 = 1;
class2 = 5;

%read in the data
data = dlmread('train.txt');
data = data(data(:,1) == class1 | data(:,1) == class2, :);

N = size(data,1);

%X matrix and labels vector
Xsv = data(:, 2:end);
labels = data(:,1);

y = zeros(size(labels));
y(labels == class1) = 1;
y(labels ~= class1) = -1;

model1 = svmtrain(y, Xsv, '-t 2 -c 0.01 -g 1')
sv = model1.sv_indices;
b = -model1.rho;
```

As you can see, I'm using C = 0.01 in the SVM algorithm. This is not <= 0. The error occurs at "sv = model1.sv_indices;" because I try to access sv_indices within model1, but model1 had an error so its empty.

I named the script above stackoverflow.m, and the error I get when I try to run it is:

```
 Error: C <= 0

model1 =

     []

Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in stackoverflow (line 19)
sv = model1.sv_indices;
```

Comment: Does it work without any of the provided options?

Comment: Yes it does work: model1 = svmtrain(y, Xsv).
It also works if C is larger than or equal to one, ie, '-c 1' for example in svmtrain.

*Note: This was working with any value of c just a week ago. I could use -c 0.00001 and it would work. I am going nuts because all of a sudden, apparently, it is giving me this error... it definitely shouldn't.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be reproducible. I tried the same code on two different computers and it works. Did you try re-making LIBSVM for MATLAB?

Comment: I will try to do that, I thought about doing something like that "restart" option. I'll let you know.

Comment: I tried running the same script and it worked. Then a few hours later, I tried using svmtrain again, and the problem of C<=0 was back again... as it is now... I ran "make" again, and then tried. Same problem... unfortunately don't know what in the world is up